# How do i deploy a Vaadin Spring server on a non-root URL

Tags: java, spring, nginx, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I am trying to deploy two instances of a Vaadin Spring application using nginx to redirect requests to the appropriate instance.

The first server should be available at `www.example.org/`, the second one at `www.example.org/second/`, both at port 80. The first server listens to port 9002, the second to port 9003.

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server_name     www.example.org localhost;
    root            /;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002/;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /second/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host/second;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host/second;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host/second;
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9003/;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The first server works completely fine.

I can also access the second server; requests to any of its URLs correctly redirect me to its login page. As soon as i click a button, i get a session expired message. From the nginx access logs, it looks like the button click triggers a POST request which goes to `/vaadinServlet/UIDL/?v-uiId=0` and returns code 200 (OK).

I believe the request should really go to `/second/vaadinServlet/UIDL/?v-uiId=0`. Thus, i am stuck on the login page.

Am i correct in my assumption that the vaadinServlet request goes to the wrong URL? If so, how do i get it to go to the correct one?

I am thinking of using nginx to extract the necessary information from the referral URL but i believe it should be possible to configure Vaadin/Spring to handle this case.

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry.

Comment: fyi: as my service which i wanted to remap is built using spring-boot and vaadin, I just add the `server.contextPath=/second` to the application configuration, and then in nginx for location _/second/_ I have  just `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002;` something like this might work four you - if still needed